# What is the pythonic way to unpack tuples as function arguments?

Tags: python, tuples

This is ugly. What's a more Pythonic way to do it?

```
import datetime

t= (2010, 10, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, 41, 0)
dt = datetime.datetime(t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6])
```

Comment: You may want to read about it in the docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Generally, you can use the `func(*tuple)` syntax. You can even pass a part of the tuple, which seems like what you're trying to do here:

```
t = (2010, 10, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, 41, 0)
dt = datetime.datetime(*t[0:7])
```

This is called *unpacking* a tuple, and can be used for other iterables (such as lists) too. Here's another example (from the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It works for arbitrary iterables.

Comment: I'd like to add that this syntax works anywhere (not just in function calls) in python 3.5, so for instance statements like `x, y, z = *(1, 2, 3)` will work without error (as it should have been a long time ago)

Comment: it there a way to do this among other list items? like `my_tuple = ("B", "C"); "%s %s %s" % ("A", *my_tuple)`?

Comment: Nevermind - I think this is a limitation of the %s string substitution method. Using `"{} {} {}".format("A", *my_tuple)` instead does the trick.

Comment: Does anyone know any details about how Python implements unpacking internally?

Answer (score 16):

Refer https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

```
 dt = datetime.datetime(*t[:7])
```