# Creating a list in Python with multiple copies of a given object in a single line

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a given Object (a string "a", a number - let's say 0, or a list `['x','y']` )

I'd like to create list containing many copies of this object, but without using a for loop:

`L = ["a", "a", ... , "a", "a"]`

or

`L = [0, 0, ... , 0, 0]`

or

`L = [['x','y'],['x','y'], ... ,['x','y'],['x','y']]`

I'm especially interested in the third case. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) is your friend.

```
L = list(itertools.repeat("a", 20)) # 20 copies of "a"

L = list(itertools.repeat(10, 20))  # 20 copies of 10

L = list(itertools.repeat(['x','y'], 20)) # 20 copies of ['x','y']
```

Note that in the third case, since lists are referred to by reference, changing one instance of ['x','y'] in the list will change all of them, since they all refer to the same list.

To avoid referencing the same item, you can use a comprehension instead to create new objects for each list element:

```
L = [['x','y'] for i in range(20)]
```

(For Python 2.x, use `xrange()` instead of `range()` for performance.)

Comment: Using an underscore instead of `i` to indicate it's a throwaway variable is good practice IMO: `L = [['x','y'] for _ in range(20)]`

Answer (score 58):

You can use the `*` operator :

```
L = ["a"] * 10
L = [0] * 10
L = [["x", "y"]] * 10
```

Be careful this create N copies of the *same item*, meaning that in the third case you create a list containing N references to the `["x", "y"]` list ; changing `L[0][0]` for example [will modify all other copies as well](/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly):

```
>>> L = [["x", "y"]] * 3
>>> L
[['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y']]
>>> L[0][0] = "z"
[['z', 'y'], ['z', 'y'], ['z', 'y']]
```

In this case you might want to use a list comprehension:

```
L = [["x", "y"] for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: +1: The * operator acting on lists is just meant to do what the original poster wanted.  The list(itertools.repeat()) solution is too big a hammer for a small nail.

Comment: You'll receive a gold bagde now, as I've upvoted it and the accepted answer, so that  this answer could have **2x** votes in comparison to the accepted answer which has minimum 10 votes. Both answers are good irrespective of the gold badge, BTW. :-)

Comment: In the last case, since you're not using the variable `i`, I believe the polite thing to do is name it `_`, i.e. `L = [['x', 'y'] for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Actually, just the last line (using the comprehension) is the correct answer, since the OP specifically asked for copies (!) of the original object. There is a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098 - that asks about repeated items, and for that case the `*` operator is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
x = <your object>
n = <times to be repeated>
L = [x for i in xrange(n)]
```

Substitute range(n) for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique instances and like to [golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), this is (slightly) shorter:

```
L = [['x', 'y'] for _ in []*10]
```

The crazy thing is that it's also (appreciably) faster:

```
>>> timeit("[['x', 'y'] for _ in [0]*1000]", number=100000)   
8.252447253966238                                             
>>> timeit("[['x', 'y'] for _ in range(1000)]", number=100000)
9.461477918957826
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps somebody. I wanted to add multiple copies of a dict into a list and came up with:

```
>>> myDict = { "k1" : "v1" }
>>> myNuList = [ myDict.copy() for i in range(6) ]
>>> myNuList
[{'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}]
>>> myNuList[1]['k1'] = 'v4'
>>> myNuList
[{'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v4'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}, {'k1': 'v3'}]
```

I found that:

```
>>> myNuList = [ myDict for i in range(6) ]
```

Did not make fresh copies of the dict.

Comment: *"Did not make fresh copies of the dict"* - that's because `myNuList = [myDict for i in range(6)]` just creates 6 references to the same `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create a `list` with repeating elements inserted *among others*, [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples) comes in handy:

```py
l = ['a', *(5*['b']), 'c']
l
Out[100]: ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

[[the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)]