# linked list output not expected in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Implement a linked list and I expect output to be `0, -1, -2, -3, ... etc.`, but it is `-98, -98, -98, -98, ... etc.`, wondering what is wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
MAXSIZE = 100
freeListHead = None

class StackNode:
    def __init__(self, value, nextNode):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = nextNode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialization for nodes and link them to be a free list
    nodes=[StackNode(-1, None)] * MAXSIZE
    freeListHead = nodes[0]
    for i in range(0, len(nodes)-1):
        nodes[i].nextNode = nodes[i+1]
        nodes[i].value = -i
    for node in nodes:
        # output -98, -98, -98, -98, ... etc.
        # exepcted output, 0, -1, -2, -3, ... etc.
        print node.value
```

Comment: @dsgdfg, thanks and how it is related to my original question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem:

```py
# initialization for nodes and link them to be a free list
nodes=[StackNode(-1, None)] * MAXSIZE
```

When you use the multiply operator, it will create multiple *references* to the **same** object, as noted [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785963/895932). So changing one node's value (as in `nodes[i].value = -i`) will affect every node since every item in the list points to the same object.

In that same linked answer, the solution is to use list comprehension like this:

```py
nodes = [StackNode(-1, None) for i in range(MAXSIZE)]
```

Also, note that you did not set the value of the last element, so the output (after the fix I suggested above) will be:

```
0, -1, -2, ..., -98, -1
```

Comment: Nice catch justhalf! Vote up and mark your reply as answer.