# How to generate a list of to repetitive items with different frequency?

Tags: python, string, list, non-repetitive

I want to generate a list of strings shown below:

```
['EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EMG', 'EMG', 'EOG']
```

but, for example, with 32 'EEG' items and 2 'EMG' and one 'EOG'.
How could I do that in one line?

I have read a StackOverflow post and I know a single repeated element can be generated with the code below:

```
['EEG']*32
```

or

```
['EEG' for _ in range(32)]
```

But I want a comprehensive list of all items with different frequencies.
I want a flat list of different items, not a nested list of lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a list in Python with multiple copies of a given object in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785954/creating-a-list-in-python-with-multiple-copies-of-a-given-object-in-a-single-lin)

Comment: @RemingtonThurber it is a little different question, and I have got a simple and good answer here!

Comment: If you already know how to replicate an element, where are you stuck?  Concatenating or joining lists is a straight look-up.

Comment: @prune yes, you are right, I did it by using the answer from Sheldore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat a list element using multiplication operator and then just add the lists together

```
answer = ['EEG']*32 + ['EMG']*2 + ['EOG']  
# ['EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EMG', 'EMG', 'EOG']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the multiplication operator then concatenate, like so:

```
['EEG']*32 + ['EMG']*2 + ['EOG']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `collections.Counter.elements` method:

```
from collections import Counter
list(Counter(EEG=32, EMG=2, EOG=1).elements())
```

This returns:

```
['EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EEG', 'EMG', 'EMG', 'EOG']
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamic way to do this would be:

```
config = [{"str":"EEG","freq":32},{"str":"EMG","freq":2},{"str":"EOG","freq":1}]
[item for sublist in ([[x["str"]]*x["freq"] for x in config]) for item in sublist]
```

to break this down:

`config` is an array of objects where `str` key is the string and `freq` key is the number of times you'd like to repeat it

`([[x["str"]]*x["freq"] for x in config])` returns an array of arrays of repeated strings

the outer part flattens this complex array into a simple list

Comment: @Mohammad Javad Generally, it's called "list comprehension" and it is a handy technique when it comes to manipulating the lists. You can check this: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python. In this particular case, I have used nested comprehension (one comprehension inside another one). Check the output of `([[x["str"]]*x["freq"] for x in config])` and you'll see what it does, and the outer statement gets you the final result from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the multiplication operator and then concatenate each list like this:

```
list = ['EEG'] * 32 + ['EMG'] * 2 + ['EOG']
```

Or you could also import Counter from collections, like another user stated, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
list(Counter(EEG=32, EMG=2, EOG=1).elements())
```

Both of these would yield a list containing 32 'EEG', 2 'EMG' and 1 'EOG'