# Changing one dict changes all dicts in a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.4

I have a list of dicts for storing data.
When I make change in one dict, that change is reflected in all dicts.

```
students = [{"marks": [], "subjects": 0}]*3
specific_student = 2
print("Before updating", students)
students[specific_student]["marks"].append(50)
students[specific_student]["subjects"] += 1
print("After updating", students)
```

I was expecting that, only last dict will get updated. but surprisingly all dicts were changed.

The **obtained result** of above program is

```
Before editing [{'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}]
After editing [{'subjects': 1, 'marks': [50]}, {'subjects': 1, 'marks': [50]}, {'subjects': 1, 'marks': [50]}]
```

But the **expected result**(only dict at position 2 gets changed) was

```
Before editing [{'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}]
After editing [{'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 0, 'marks': []}, {'subjects': 1, 'marks': [50]}]
```

Can some one explain this strange behavior and suggest a solution to obtain the expected result?

Comment: It's all the same dict, repeated three times. It's because of how you create the list (with `* 3`), it just creates a list with three times the same reference. See questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785954/creating-a-list-in-python-with-multiple-copies-of-a-given-object-in-a-single-lin for better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .copy() onto your list, else it would be a link of your dict and not a new dict with the same values.
Note that you need to use .copy() on EVERY dict and list you want to copy, even those in your dict/list