# How to get two variables from the previous function in python?

Tags: python

I'm very new at python so I'm still learning some things. But I'm doing this code and I need to know how to get the x and y variables from the "getHumanMove" function so that I can use it in the "getPiles" function

```
def getHumanMove(x,y):
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        x=int(input("Which pile would you like to take from?(1 or 2)"))
        y=int(input("How many would you like from pile "+ str(x)+ "? "))
        if pile1 and pile2<y:
            print("pile " +str(x)+ " does not have that many chips. Try again.")
        elif y==0:
            print("You must take at least one chip. Try again.")
        else:
            print("That was a legal move. Thank You.")
        finished = True
    return x,y

def getPiles(pile1, pile2):
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    #################################Here is where I need to put the x, y variables 
    pile1= pile1
    pile2= pile2
    if temp_x == 1:
        pile1= pile1- temp_y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
    elif temp_x == 2:
        pile2= pile1- temp_y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
        return pile1, pile2

##############################Main##############################
move= getHumanMove(pile1, pile2)

pile= getPiles(pile1, pile2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in your call to getPiles:

```
pile = getPiles(pile1, pile2, move)
```

and then in your getPiles definition:

```
def getPiles(pile1, pile2, move):
    x, y = move
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you mean:

```
x,y = getHumanMove(pile1, pile2)
pile1, pile2 = getPiles(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**tuple unpacking**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238361/2670792):

```
move = getHumanMove(pile1, pile2)
pile = getPiles(*move)
```

Or get each variable separately, so you can pass them separately too:

```
move1, move2 = getHumanMove(pile1, pile2)
pile = getPiles(move1, move2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a function is returning two values, you can do

```
value1, value2 = some_function(argument1, argument2, argument3, ...)
```

to store the two return values in `value1` and `value2`.