# Networkx Python Edges Comparison

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have been trying to build a graph for a project and I have been trying to identify newly added edges after populating it with more information.

For instance below you can see its first and second iteration:

---------------------- General Info Graph H-----------------------------

```
Total number of Nodes in Graph:  2364
Total number of Edges:  3151
```

---------------------- General Info Graph G -----------------------------

```
Total number of Nodes in Graph:  6035
Total number of Edges:  11245
```

The problem I have been facing is when I try to identify newly added edges using the code:

```
counter = 0
edges_all = list(G.edges_iter(data=True)) 
edges_before = list(H.edges_iter(data=True)) 
print "How many edges in old graph: ", len(edges_before)
print "How many edges in new graph: ", len(edges_all)
edge_not_found = []
for edge in edges_all:
    if edge in edges_before:
        counter += 1
    else:
        edge_not_found.append(edge)
print "Edges found: ", counter
print "Not found: ", len(edge_not_found)
```

And I have been getting these results:

```
How many edges in old graph:  3151
How many edges in new graph:  11245
Edges found:  1601
Not found:  9644
```

I can't understand why I am getting 1601 found instead of 11245-3151 = 8094

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR:  There's a simple explanation for what you see, and if you get to the end, there is a much shorter way to write your code (with a lot of explanation along the way).

---

First note that it looks like `Edges found` is intended to be the number of edges that are in both `H` and `G`.  So it should only have 3151, not 8094.  8094 should be `Not found`.  Note that the number of edges found, 1601, is about half the number that you would expect.  That makes sense because:

I believe the problem you are having is that when networkx lists out the edges an edge might appear as `(a,b)` in `edges_before`.  However in `edges_after`, it might appear in the list as `(b,a)`.

So `(b,a)` will not be in `edges_before`.  It will fail your test.  Assuming the edge orders aren't correlated between when they are listed for `H` and `G`, you'd expect to find about half of them pass.  You can do a different test to see if `(b,a)` is an edge of `H`.  This is `H.has_edge(b,a)`

A straightforward improvement:

```
for edge in edges_all:
    if H.has_edge(edge[0],edge[1]):
        counter += 1
    else:
        edge_not_found.append(edge)
```

This lets you avoid even defining `edges_before`.

You can also avoid defining `edges_all` through a better improvement:

```
for edge in G.edges_iter(data=True):
    if H.has_edge(edge[0],edge[1]):
        etc
```

Note: I've written it as `H.has_edge(edge[0],edge[1])` to make clear what's happening.  A more sophisticated way to write it is `H.has_edge(*edge)`.  The `*edge` notation [unpacks the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples).

Finally, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) gives a better way to get edge_not_found:

```
edge_not_found = [edge for edge in G.edges_iter(data=True) if not H.has_edge(*edge)]
```

This creates a list made up of `edge`s which are in `G` but not in `H`.

Putting this all together (and using the `.size()` command to count edges in a network), we arrive at a cleaner version:

```
print "How many edges in old graph: ", H.size()
print "How many edges in new graph: ", G.size()
edge_not_found = [edge for edge in G.edges_iter(data=True) if not H.has_edge(*edge)]
print "Not found: ", len(edge_not_found)
print "Edges found: ", G.size()-len(edge_not_found)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it worked like a charm. The only thing is for the edges_not_found line to work as expected if someone has populated the graph edges with data, it should be:
    edge_not_found = [edge for edge in G.edges_iter() if not H.has_edge(*edge)]
or else it returns TypeError: has_edge() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given).