# How to 'unpack' a list or tuple in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a Python program to play Tic Tac Toe, using Numpy arrays with "X" represented by `1` and "O" by `0`. The class includes a function to place a mark on the board:

```
import numpy as np

class Board():
    def __init__(self, grid = np.ones((3,3))*np.nan):
        self.grid = grid

    def place_mark(self, pos, mark):
        self.grid[pos[0],pos[1]] = mark
```

so that, for example,

```
board = Board()
board.place_mark([0,1], 1)
print board.grid
```

yields

```
[[ nan   1.  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
```

I was wondering if the `pos[0], pos[1]` argument in the `place_mark` function could somehow be replaced by the 'unpacked' contents of `pos` (which is always a list of length 2). In Ruby this would be done using the splat operator: `*pos`, but this does not appear to be valid syntax in Python.

Comment: `board.place_mark((0,1), 1)` and `self.grid[pos] = mark`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Numpy, there's a difference between indexing with lists and multi-dimensional indexing. `self.grid[[0,1]]` is equivalent to concatenating `self.grid[0]` and `self.grid[1]`, each 3x1 arrays, into a 3x2 array.

If you use tuples instead of lists for indexing, then it will be correctly interpreted as multi-dimensional indexing: `self.grid[(0, 1)]` is interpreted the same as `self.grid[0, 1]`.

There is a `*` operator for unpacking sequences, but in the context of function arguments only, at least in Python 2. So, with lists you could also do this:

```
def place_mark(self, mark, x, y):
    self.grid[x, y] = mark

place_mark(1, *[0, 1])
```

NB. [(Expanded usefulness of `*` in Python 3)](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/07/31/python-faq-why-should-i-use-python-3/#unpacking)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Lukasz, the input argument should be a tuple. In this example it can be converted to one:

```
def place_mark(self, pos, mark):
    self.grid[tuple(pos)] = mark
```

My question is not the same [What is the pythonic way to unpack tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples) because `pos` does not constitute the input arguments to a function, but rather the indices of a 2-dimensional array.