# Python variables in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little question about variables. My main language is Java (and I'm learning Python) so, I have a problem calling a variable in a function, it doesn't refresh its new value:

```
# Values
global e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c, altx, alty, x, y

def getValues():
    print("Taking Ax + By = C:")
    e1x = float(input("Value of x in first equation: "))
    #...
    if(confirm()): # A function I ommited 'cause its irrelevant
        return e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c
    else:
        getValues()

def calculateValues():
    # Stuff with variables


# MAIN
getValues()
calculateValues()
```

I tried to write it without the *global*, tried to use the *self* word but, It doesn't work. (Using Python 3)

ERROR:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E002_GaussSeidel.py", line 41, in <module>
      calculateValues()
   File "E002_GaussSeidel.py", line 34, in calculateValues
      print(str(e1x))
 NameError: name 'e1x' is not defined
```

Comment: Burn *global e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c, altx, alty, x, y*. You don't really want to  use globals. You would also use `self` in a class method where self refers to the instance the method would be called on. If you want to use that logic then actually create a class not just functions.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description.  Do you get an error?  If so, what's the full traceback?  Does it behave unexpectedly?  If so, describe the expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: Python says "e1x is not defined" when I try to use it on 'calculateValues()' but I declared on top and initialized on the function which actually returns those values @SvenMarnach

Comment: @AlfonsoIzaguirreMartínez You are supposed to move the global decl to the top of `getValues()`. but you don't want to use global variables because they are evil.

Comment: @AlfonsoIzaguirreMartínez This should be included in your question, including the full traceback of the error.  You can't declare variables in Python, and `global` outside a function definition doesn't do anything.

Comment: The `global` statement only applies to *functions*. Python determines that a name is a local in a function if you *bind to it* (assignment is one form of binding). The `global` statement tells Python to override that determination. You didn't use `global` in the function, you used it elsewhere.

Comment: the duplicate is not what you want. because global variables are evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `global` within your function. Outside it does nothing.

```
def getValues():
    global e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c, altx, alty, x, y
    print("Taking Ax + By = C:")
    e1x = float(input("Value of x in first equation: "))
    #...
    if(confirm()): # A function I ommited 'cause its irrelevant
        return e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c
    else:
        getValues()

def calculateValues():
    # Stuff with variables


# MAIN
getValues()
calculateValues()
```

But why do you need global variables? Are you going to use those variables outside your function? `global` is only necessary if you need to modify values that exist outside the scope of the function.

Reformat your code to be like:

```
def getValues():
    print("Taking Ax + By = C:")
    e1x = float(input("Value of x in first equation: "))
    #...
    if(confirm()): # A function I ommited 'cause its irrelevant
        return e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c
    else:
        getValues()

def calculateValues(values):
    # Stuff with variables


# MAIN
calculateValues(getValues())
```

Instead of passing information with global variables, this passes information by return values. [There are hundreds of articles on why global variables are evil.](https://www.google.com/search?q=global%20variables%20are%20evil)

`values` holds the returned variables `e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c`. It is accessible using list index notation. If you want to refer to the variables by their names, use:

```
#...
def calculateValues(e1x, e1y, e1c, e2x, e2y, e2c):
    # Stuff with variables


# MAIN
calculateValues(*getValues())
```

`*foo` is list unpacking notation. It is an advanced topic, but it is useful in your situation. You can read more about list unpacking [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238361/1459669)

Comment: Yes, I'll use the in calculateValues()

Comment: @AlfonsoIzaguirreMartínez No, you don't. `calculateValues()` should call `getValues()` and use the return value. Or, you could pass the result of `getValues()` to `calculateValues()`. Global variables are evil.