# Pandas dataframe of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe that I create from a list (which is created from a spark rdd) by calling:

`newRdd = rdd.map(lambda row: Row(row.__fields__ + ["tag"])(row + (tagScripts(row), ))).collect()` and then `df = pd.DataFrame(newRdd)`

My data ends up looking like a dataframe of tuples as shown below:

```
0  (2017-06-21, Sun, ATL, 10)
1  (2017-06-21, Sun, ATL, 11)
2  (2017-06-21, Sun, ATL, 11)
```

but I need it to look like a standard table with column headers as such:

```
date       dayOfWeek    airport   val1  
2017-06-11    Sun         ATL     11
```

I'm honestly out of ideas on this one and need some help. I've tried a lot of different things and nothing has seemed to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the format of newRdd? maybe show a print of it...

Comment: It's a list object type

Comment: And then once converted it becomes a pandas dataframe type

Comment: ok it is a list, but the elements of this list are what?

Comment: The elements are of tuple type after the rdd transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*df.A],columns = ['date','dayOfWeek','airport','val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6'])
```

i supposed the column name in the dataframe you already have is `A`.

you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples) for tuples unpacking.

Hope this was helpful. in there are any questions please let me know.