# replacing a string in python list with another string

Tags: python

currently my loops stops at replacing 1 with the answer.
how do i loop it so it replaces all 4 blanks with the 4 answers?

```
easyQuiz = "There are ___1___ countries in the world. The countries with the biggest landmass is ___2___. The coldest continent in the world is ___3___. ___4___ is the capital of China"

blanks = ["___1___","___2___","___3___","___4___"]

easyAnswer = ["195","Russia","Antartica","Beijing"]

#asks users to choose difficulty level
question = raw_input("Shall we start? Easy, Medium, Hard?")


if question == "Easy" or question == "easy":
    answerChoice = easyAnswer

answerChoice = answerList(question)
newprompt = []
newlist = []
index = 0
maxblanks = 3

for quizwords in difficulty(question).split():

    if quizwords == "1" :
        quizwords = quizwords.replace("1",answerChoice[index])


    elif quizwords == "2" :
        quizwords = quizwords.replace("2",answerChoice[index])

        index = index + 1
    newlist.append(quizwords)
    joinedlist = " ".join(newlist)
```

Comment: What's `answerList` and `difficulty`?

Comment: You probably want to use string formatting here: http://pyformat.info/

Comment: Also, if `quizwords == "1"`, you can just do `quizwords = answerChoice[index]` instead of `replace`, but is this really what you intended?

Comment: If you expect any help, post a MCVE including expected results (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting

```
def easyQuiz(vals):
      return """
There are {} countries in the world.
The countries with the biggest landmass is {}.
The coldest continent in the world is {}.
{} is the capital of China""".format(*vals)

print(easyQuiz(("___1___","___2___","___3___","___4___")))
# There are ___1___ countries in the world.
# The countries with the biggest landmass is ___2___.
# The coldest continent in the world is ___3___.
# ___4___ is the capital of China

print(easyQuiz(("195","Russia","Antartica","Beijing")))
# There are 195 countries in the world.
# The countries with the biggest landmass is Russia.
# The coldest continent in the world is Antartica.
# Beijing is the capital of China
```

Comment: thank you!
what does the * in the .format(*vals) mean?

Comment: @nicholasgwee you are welcome. It's [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples).

Comment: may i ask how can i replace only the 2nd {} in the question although there are four values

Comment: @nicholasgwee as a simple approach you could still replace all 4, but for 1, 2, 4 just insert the placeholders. E.g. `print(easyQuiz(("___1___","Russia","___3___","___4___")))`.

Comment: Thank you so much i managed to format the blanks based on users input for the correct answers! much appreciated!

Comment: @nicholasgwee happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the `blanks` with the corresponding `easyAnswer` and `replace` those in a loop.

```
for blank, answer in zip(blanks, easyAnswer):
    easyQuiz = easyQuiz.replace(blank, answer)
```

Or `zip` to a `dict` and use `re.sub` with a callback:

```
answer_dict = dict(zip(blanks, easyAnswer))
result = re.sub("___\d___", lambda m: answer_dict[m.group()], easyQuiz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting with `regex`:

```
import re
easyQuiz = "There are ___1___ countries in the world. The countries with the biggest landmass is ___2___. The coldest continent in the world is ___3___. ___4___ is the capital of China"
easyAnswer = ["195","Russia","Antartica","Beijing"]
answers = re.sub('___\d+___', '{}', easyQuiz).format(*easyAnswer)
```

Output:

```
'There are 195 countries in the world. The countries with the biggest landmass is Russia. The coldest continent in the world is Antartica. Beijing is the capital of China'
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit confusing, especially 'difficulty' and 'answerList'. Assuming, 'answerList' returns a list of four answers. Your loop will depend upon difficulty(question).split(). My hunch is your loop is iterating only once, and the index is not getting updated after that hence loops stops at replacing 1 with the answer.