# Returning positional arguments from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The class( people ) requires 3 arguments called "name, middle_name and surname" and I am trying to give these arguments like down below:

```
    def argument():
        name = input("name : ")
        middle_name = input("middle name : ")
        last_name = input("last name : ")
        return name,middle_name,last_name
   person = people(argument())
```

But somehow its not working, the error message I am getting:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments
```

Comment: Can you post your people class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the following definition of people:

```
class people:

    def __init__(self, name, middle_name, last_name):
        self.name = name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.last_name = last_name
```

This should work:

```
def argument():
    name = input("name : ")
    middle_name = input("middle name : ")
    last_name = input("last name : ")
    return name, middle_name, last_name


person = people(*argument())

print(person.name)
print(person.middle_name)
print(person.last_name)
```

Note the `*` before the call to argument `argument()`. This is known as [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples)

Comment: Thanks, yeah it worked . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the star/explode notation to unpack them

```
person = people(*argument())
```

---

As a random tip, in Python, we typically Capitalize class names, so I'd recommend using something like a `Person` class instead of trying to differentiate classes and instances based on plurality (`people` vs `person`). Just do `Person` (the class) vs `person` (an instance).

Answer (score 2):

`argument` function will return tuple. you need to unpack it in order to supply 3 positional arguments
`person = people(*argument())`