# python: ctypes, read POINTER(c_char) in python

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a ctypes field that is a `POINTER(c_char)` (it had to be, per the documentation, c_char_p didn't work for my application: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p)

> For a general character pointer that may also point to binary data, POINTER(c_char) must be used.

However, this usage recommended by ctypes itself seems to have the downside that, it claims to be a pointer to a single character, however, it isn't, it's a pointer to an array of bytes.

How can I read the array returned by the ctypes fucntion (I know the `length`) in Python? Trying to index it like `foo[0:len]` where `foo` is a `POINTER(c_char)` blows up with `TypeError: 'c_char' object is not subscriptable`

I can print the first character of the bytestring using either `print(foo)` or `print(foo[0])`

I was thinking that `ctypes.cast` might work, however I don't know how to pass it the length of the cast (as in interpret the first N bytes from address foo as a `bytes` object)

EDIT: some code.

So I have a structure:

```
class foo(Structure):
_fields_ = [("state", c_int),
            ("type", c_int),
            ("len", c_int),
            ("payload", POINTER(c_char))]  # according to th following the python bytes are already unsinged https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/695078-ctypes-unsigned-char
```

And I have another function that returns a `POINTER(foo)`

```
lib3 = CDLL(....so)
f = lib3.f
f.restype = POINTER(foo)
```

I call `f`, which returns a `POINTER(foo)`:

```
ptrf = f(....)
```

And then I was trying to access `ptrf.payload`. The following code works:

```
def get_payload(ptr_to_foo):

    val = cast(ptr_to_foo.contents.payload, c_char_p).value
    return val[:ptr_to_foo.contents.len]
```

So I do

```
 ptrf = f(....)
 get_payload(ptrf)
```

I was wondering whether the `get_payload` function would be written more easily.

Comment: Can you share some code / details (how the func is called what args are being passed to it, who allocates the array)? Maybe the whole approach is wrong. The *TypeError* that you get denotes that *foo* is a *c\_char* (not a pointer). I am able to index a `ctypes.LP_c_char` (which was created from a char array).

Comment: @CristiFati question updated to include more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) states, you must **not** use *c_char_p* with binary data. 
Of course that can be ignored, but then surprises (string silently truncated) may occur.

Although it could be exemplified in *~5* lines of code, pasting the whole thing:

*dll.c*:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

#define LEN 5


typedef struct CharPtrWrapperTag {
    int len;
    char *data;
} CharPtrWrapper;


DLL_EXPORT CharPtrWrapper *get() {
    CharPtrWrapper *ret = malloc(sizeof(CharPtrWrapper));
    ret->len = LEN;
    ret->data = malloc(LEN * sizeof(char));
    ret->data[0] = 'A';
    ret->data[1] = 'B';
    ret->data[2] = 0;
    ret->data[3] = 'C';
    ret->data[4] = 'D';
    return ret;
}


DLL_EXPORT void release(CharPtrWrapper *pWrap) {
    if (pWrap) {
        free(pWrap->data);
        pWrap->data = NULL;
        pWrap->len = 0;
        free(pWrap);
    }
}
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


DLL_NAME = "./dll.dll"
CharPtr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

class CharPtrWrapper(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("len", ctypes.c_int),
        ("data", CharPtr),
    ]


CharPtrWrapperPtr = ctypes.POINTER(CharPtrWrapper)


def main():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    get = dll.get
    get.restype = CharPtrWrapperPtr
    release = dll.release
    release.argtypes = [CharPtrWrapperPtr]
    wrap_ptr = get()
    wrap = wrap_ptr.contents
    print("{:}\n    Len: {:d}".format(wrap, wrap.len))
    for idx in range(wrap.len):
        print("        {:d}: {:}".format(idx, wrap.data[idx]))

    s = ctypes.cast(wrap.data, ctypes.c_char_p).value[:wrap.len]
    print("\nctypes.c_char_p cast: {:}".format(s))

    CharArr = ctypes.c_char * wrap.len
    char_arr = CharArr(*wrap.data[:wrap.len])
    print("CharArr: {:}".format(char_arr.raw))
    release(wrap_ptr)
    print("\nDone.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055103298]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /MD dll.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll.dll
> dll.c
>    Creating library dll.lib and object dll.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
> dll.dll
> dll.exp
> dll.lib
> dll.obj
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> <__main__.CharPtrWrapper object at 0x000001279250D248>
>     Len: 5
>         0: b'A'
>         1: b'B'
>         2: b'\x00'
>         3: b'C'
>         4: b'D'
>
> ctypes.c_char_p cast: b'AB'
> CharArr: b'AB\x00CD'
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: this most definitely saved me from a huge gotcha! This works great thank you

Comment: there is some magical stuff going on here, *wrap.data[:wrap.len] looks like a pointer dereference but it isn't. I modified your answer slightly to return `char_arr[0:len]`, instead of printing it. Maybe I should also try this `raw` attribute.

Comment: That's *tuple unpacking* (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples). No need the slice `[0:len]` (which is the same as `[:len]` btw :) ), because *char\_arr* will not be longer than *len*.

Comment: but returning without the `[0:len]` returns a ctypes char_array object, whereas slicing it seems to return a `bytes` object. The caller is expecting the bytes object, not the ctypes representation.

Comment: Then return `char_array.raw`  (which the slice operator takes and (unnecessarily)  slices). But at the end, do it as you consider best. I'm a bit of a maniac when it comes about efficiency, code being run more than once, ....

Comment: ok returning raw seems to be a drop in replacement for [0:len], so going with that per your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly have a `POINTER(c_char)` type, it is subscriptable.  In the future provide code that reproduces your issue:

```
>>> p = cast(create_string_buffer(b'Hello, world!'),POINTER(c_char))
>>> p
<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x000001C2F6B58848>
>>> p[0]
b'H'
>>> p[:14]
b'Hello, world!\x00'
>>> cast(p,c_char_p).value  # only if known to be nul-terminated
b'Hello, world!'
```