# Ctypes. How to pass struct by reference?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes, dynamic-library

I try to write Python wrapper for C library using ctypes.
So far I have:

**C.h**

```c
    typedef struct
    {
        int erorrCode;
        char * Key;

    } A;

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    EXPORT void __stdcall DestroyA(A &input);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
```

**C.cpp**

```c
    EXPORT void __stdcall DestroyA(A &input)
    {
        delete []input.Key;
    }
```

**Python.py**

```py
    import sys
    import ctypes

    class A(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("erorrCode", ctypes.c_int),
            ("Key", ctypes.c_char_p)]


    try:
      libapi = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
    except OSError:
      print("Unable to load RAPI library")
      sys.exit()

    DestroyA = libapi.DestroyA
    libapi.DestroyA.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(A)]
    libapi.DestroyA.restype = None

    a = A(1,b'random_string')

    DestroyA(ctypes.byref(a)) #!!!here is segmentation fault
```

So, how can I fix the segmentation fault error?

Note: I cannot change the code on the C ++ side as long as there is a way to fix it on the Python side.

Comment: Why are your functions *\_\_stdcall*?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to call ```DestroyA```? Because you are allocating a ```c_char_p``` in Python here ```a = A(1,b'random_string')```. Thus Python should handle the memory for its allocated objects. This means your library function does not manage the address it should "delete" and gives you a segmentation fault.

Comment: Another thing is that you are trying to call a function that is flagged with ```__stdcall```. But your library is loaded as CDLL ```ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary``` which means dll exports should have ```__cdecl``` (see here https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

You have here ***Undefined Behavior*** (*UB*).

*Python* has builtin memory management for its objects, including *CTypes* ones. 
So, every time an object (*PyObject* which is basically anything - including a *Python* *int*), *Python* invokes one of the *malloc* functions family under the hood in order to allocate memory. Conversely, when the object is destroyed (manually or by *GC*), *free* is called.

What happened:

1. You created the object (behind the scenes, *Python* allocated some memory)
2. You called *free* on the object allocated by *Python* (which is wrong, not to mention that you also crossed the *.dll* boundary)

You need to call *free* **only on pointers that you allocated**. One such example: [[SO]: python: ctypes, read POINTER(c_char) in python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103298/python-ctypes-read-pointerc-char-in-python/55128773#55128773).

If you want to get rid of the object (and thus free the memory that it uses), let *Python* do it for you:

```py
del a
```

Additional remarks:

- You're using *__stdcall* functions with *ctypes.CDLL*. Again, that's *UB* (on *32bit*). Use the "regular" calling convention (*__cdecl*)
- You're passing a reference. That's *C++* specific (although it's only a *const ptr*). To be *C* compatible, use:

  ```c
  EXPORT void destroyA(A *pInput);
  ```