# Using tuples with .format in python

Tags: python, format, tuples

while using the `.format()` with text filling, I encounter this error.

what I have:

```
tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')
text = "Hi {} hello {} ola {}"
#command I tried to run
text.format(tuple)
```

The output I am aiming for:

```
 Hi a hello b ola c
```

the error I get:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

not sure how to fix this!

Comment: Unpack the `tuple`. ie, `text.format(*tuple)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use an [iterable unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> "{}, {}, {}".format(*t)
'1, 2, 3'
```

Side note: Do not use `tuple` as a variable name, as that is a reserved [Python built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) function (i.e. `tuple([1, 2, 3])`).

Comment: @FelipeFaria I'm sorry, but your terminology needs some updating :)

Answer (score 3):

@FelipeFaria's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926173/5168011) is the correct solution, the explanation is that in `text.format(tuple)` you are essentially adding the entire tuple to the first place holder

```
print(text.format(tuple))
```

if worked, will print something like

```
Hi (a, b, c) hello { } ola { }
```

`format` is expecting 3 values, since it found only one it raise `tuple index out of range` exception.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed to the previous answer "do not use a tuple as a variable name,". I modified your code now you can try this. It will be easier to understand.

```
tup = ('a', 'b', 'c')
text = "Hi {} hello {} ola {}"
tex = text.format(*tup)
print(tex)
```

and for unpacking the tuple you should add *

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples) for `How to unpack a tuple in Python.`

I am quoting one of the answer:

Generally, you can use the `func(*tuple)` syntax. You can even pass a part of the tuple, which seems like what you're trying to do here:

```
t = (2010, 10, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, 41, 0)
dt = datetime.datetime(*t[0:7])
```

This is called unpacking a tuple, and can be used for other iterables (such as lists) too.

For you, you can try (as mentioned in one of the answer, you should avoid using any reserved keyword for your variables and methods):

```
t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
text = "Hi {} hello {} ola {}".format(*t)
print(text)
```