# Changing dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, format

I want to change a dictionary below ...

```
dict = {
    'A': [('B', 1), ('C', 3), ('D', 7)],
    'B': [('D', 5)],
    'C': [('D', 12)] }
```

into other form like this:

```
dict = [
('A', 'B', 1), ('A', 'C', 3), ('A', 'D', 7),
('B', 'D', 5), ('C', 'D', 12)]
```

This is what I done.

```
dict = {
 'A': [('B', 1), ('C', 3), ('D', 7)],
 'B': [('D', 5)],
 'C': [('D', 12)] }

if(i[0] in dict):
    value = dict[i[0]]
    newvalue = i[1],i[2]
    value.append(newvalue)
    dict1[i[0]]=value

else:
    newvalue = i[1],i[2]
    l=[]
    l.append(newvalue)
    dict[i[0]]=l
```

print(dict)

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a question or problem doing this?

Comment: Can you confirm that `('B', 'C', 12)` is in the expected output? I think what you want might be  `('B', 'D', 5)` instead. And also, please post what you have tried so far so that people can go from there to provide help.

Comment: Please confirm if expected output is correct and also Please share if you have written some code to do transformation

Answer (score 1):

Python tuple is an immutable object. Hence any operation that tries to modify it (like append) is not allowed. However, following workaround can be used.

```
dict = {
    'A': [('B', 1), ('C', 3), ('D', 7)],
    'B': [('D', 5)],
    'C': [('D', 12)] }

new_dict = []

for key, tuple_list in dict.items():
    for tuple_item in tuple_list:
        entry = list(tuple_item)
        entry.append(key)
        new_dict.append(tuple(entry))

print(new_dict)
```

Output:
`[('B', 1, 'A'), ('C', 3, 'A'), ('D', 7, 'A'), ('D', 5, 'B'), ('D', 12, 'C')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dictionary using `.items()`. Notice that each value is by itself a list of tuples. We want to unpack each tuple, so we need a nested for-loop as shown below. `res` is the output list that we will populate within the loop.

```
res = []
for key, values in dict.items():
    for value in values:
        res.append((key, value[0], value[1]))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> res
[('A', 'B', 1), ('A', 'C', 3), ('A', 'D', 7), ('B', 'D', 5), ('C', 'D', 12)]
```

---

**EDIT**: If `value` is a tuple of more than two elements, we would modify the last line as follows, using [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples):

```
res.append((key, *value))
```

This effectively unpacks all the elements of `value`. For example,

```
>>> test = (1, 2, 3)
>>> (0, *test)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What if the tuple have more than two elements?

Comment: Then we wouldn't be able to use `res.append((key, value[0], value[1]))`. Instead, I would use a different mode of tuple unpacking, like `res.append((key, *value))`. However, given the sample input and output of the OP, I think the implementation above would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple aproach could be

```
new_dict = []
for letter1, list in dict.items():
    for letter2, value in list:
        new_dict.append([letter1, letter2, value])
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension;

```
dict_ = {
    'A': [('B', 1), ('C', 3), ('D', 7)],
    'B': [('D', 5)],
    'C': [('D', 12)] }

result = [(key, value[0], value[1]) for key, list_ in dict_.items() for value in list_]
```

Output;

```
[('A', 'B', 1), ('A', 'C', 3), ('A', 'D', 7), ('B', 'D', 5), ('C', 'D', 12)]
```