# IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python, index-error

I am following a tutorial and I don't know why I got this error:

```
    <ipython-input-61-d59f7a5a07ab> in extract_featuresets(ticker)
      2     tickers, df = process_data_for_labels(ticker)
      3     df['{}_target'.format(ticker)] = list(map(buy_sell_hold,
----> 4                                              df['{}_{}1d'.format(ticker)],
      5                                              df['{}_{}2d'.format(ticker)],
      6                                              df['{}_{}3d'.format(ticker)],

IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Here is my code:

```
tickers, df = process_data_for_labels(ticker)
df['{}_target'.format(ticker)] = list(map(buy_sell_hold,
                                         df['{}_{}1d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}2d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}3d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}4d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}5d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}6d'.format(ticker)],
                                         df['{}_{}7d'.format(ticker)],))
```

Here is the link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPp80YM2v7k

Comment: `ticker` must be a two-element tuple because there are two placeholders in the format string. Is it?

Comment: you should be calling `tickers` instead of `ticker`... notice the previous line only unpacks one element `'{}_target'.format(ticker)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your format string need two arguments in `format` while you are only passing in one `ticker` as argument.

If `ticker` is a two element list or tuple, you can do this:

```
df['{}_{}1d'.format(*ticker)]
```

Otherwise remove one curly brackets:

```
df['{}_1d'.format(ticker)]
```

Comment: In Python `*` is used to unpack iterables (see [What is the Pythonic way to unpack tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples))

Answer (score 6):

If you want same value in `{ }` of

```
df['{ }_{ }1d'.format(*ticker)]
```

Try like it this:

```
df['{0}_{0}1d'.format(*ticker)]
```

I solved my problem similar your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I was replacing values in a templated unit test python file. It contained an old string formatting command:

```py
# bad code
self.logger.error("Test Case 1: FAILED with reason: {}".format(failure_message))

# fixed code
self.logger.error("Test Case 1: FAILED with reason: {{}}".format(failure_message))
```

and this was causing the issue with a misleading error.

I had to make sure any single pair of curly braces in the python code were double braced to maintain single braces for when the formatting finished.