# Why there is an issu

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple while loop but there is a problem:

```python
import random

weekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

n = 0
while n < len(weekDays):
    diceRoll = random.randint(4, 6)
    print("On {} perform {} reps per set".format(weekDays[n]))
    n = n + 1
```

The issue I do not get it:

> print("On {} perform {} reps per set".format(weekDays[n]))
> IndexError:Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Will be appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: In accordance with [ask], please research your issue before posting here. This is a duplicate of [IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655115/indexerror-replacement-index-1-out-of-range-for-positional-args-tuple)

Comment: How many placeholders do you have in the string? How many values are you giving to `format`?

Comment: Why use a `while` loop at all? `for day in weekDays: print("...".format(day, diceRol))`. You aren't using `n` except to index the list, so you can get rid of it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Your `format` call is missing an argument (`diceRoll`).  It's easier to keep track of the values you're formatting if you use f-strings rather than `format`, since they go straight in the string:

```
import random

weekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
for day in weekDays:
    diceRoll = random.randint(4, 6)
    print(f"On {day} perform {diceRoll} reps per set")
```

Answer (score 0):

There needs two arguments in `print("On {} perform {} reps per set".format(weekDays[n]))`.

You could change it to `print("On {} perform reps per set".format(weekDays[n]))`. It will be worked.